# Two columns non overlapping div layout

Tags: html, css, layout

It seems I can't really solve this problem after two whole days of research and various tests.
I need a div which contains two div standing side by side as two columns, like in the image.
http://i.gyazo.com/bbfdcf09a2178fc0e662c59fae995988.png

The first div (in white) must assume the right size to contain properly the two columns.

I tried basically two ways:
1) make the two columns to float:left and add a clear:both empty div. The problem is, when one column become taller then the first, it wraps around it.
The code is:

```
<div style="position:relative; background-color:#fff">
<div style="float:left; width:50px;">
    this is the first column
</div>
<div style="float:left; font-family:trebuchet MS, sans-serif;">
    The second column..contains various divs.
    <div> a header </div>
    <div> some more contents </div>
    <div> a footer </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

2) make the two columns position:absolute and place them manually. It works, but I can't get the container to resize properly..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of this bit of code in relation to the rest of the code on your page, but can you make the outer div float? Because it contains two divs that do float but it itself does not, it collapses and its white background doesn't extend down to match the height of the divs within it. Having it float too means it does and you could also get rid of the `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` tag.

I've stripped out some of your code to leave just the crux of what I'm getting at:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <div style="float:left; width: 50px;">
        this is the first column
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        The second column..contains various divs.
        <div> a header </div>
        <div> some more contents </div>
        <div> a footer </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container is not the problem, I will explain better with this: I'm trying to create the template for comment messages. When the message is short, everything runs good, like here http://i.gyazo.com/c0d7a9d14c293aecf528cc298315b9fc.png .
when the message is longer, it shifts under the avatar like this:
http://i.gyazo.com/0902a435ea4c1dfc5196594cd8b5ea53.png
There's nothing else in the html code other then that.

Comment: I believe the right-hand div drops below the left-hand div when the content in the right-hand div is long because of widths. As your code currently is, the left-hand div always has a width of 50 pixels, and the right-hand div expands to be the width of whatever content is within it. When there are enough words to span the entire page, its width plus the left-hand div of 50 pixels is too wide for them to sit side-by-side within the container div, i.e. 100% plus 50 pixels inside a container of 100% width.

Within the scope of your design are you able to give the right-hand div a width too?